# Subprocess + php + django. Подводные камни

Tags: php, django, apache2, subprocess

Есть очень сложный скрипт на php, написанный из разряда "кручу верчу обмануть хочу" - криптография - генератор лицензий софта.

Он крутился на старой версии сайта. Но времена меняются, и ныне сайт успешно переехал с php на django.

Проблема в том, что переписать этот скрипт на питоне весьма проблематично и трудозатратно, потому хотелось бы только его запускать, но включать на сервере поддержку php - не безопасно.

Есть идея запускать php непосредственно через django вызовом subprocess аля

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['php ./old_scripts/licgen.php %s ' % lic_request, '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

Интересует мнение сообщества - насколько это безопасно, и какие могут быть *подводные камни*.

Comment: Скорее всего будет норм, если в lic_request никакая бяка не появится

Comment: @andreymal а для lic_request там внутри побайтовый разбор, и может только exeption типа невозможности разделить разряды на 4 части возникнуть, если подсунуть какую нибудь "бяку" :)

Comment: Ну в общем проверяйте ваш разбор, чтобы не оказалось `lic_request = '&rm -rf /*&#'` :)

Comment: Хотя вообще почему у вас написано `['php ./old_scripts/licgen.php %s ' % lic_request, '-a']`, а не `['php', './old_scripts/licgen.php', lic_request, '-a']` ?

Comment: @andreymal Вот... Я как раз по этому поводу и задал вопрос. Теоретически такое вполне можно подсунуть. Хорошая наводка.

Comment: Напишите как ответ, баллов Вам поставим.

Comment: Я на всякий случай просто сделаю replace('&', '')

Comment: Тогда вместо `&` просто напишут `;`

Comment: От ответа я пока воздержусь: насколько я знаю, во второй вариант записи аргументов (из моего предыдущего комментария; а ваш вариант по-моему вообще не должен работать) никакую бяку подсунуть вроде не получится, но я в этом точно не уверен, пусть ответит кто-нибудь тот, кто работал с subprocess больше чем я

Comment: ######################## **** SECURITY ****** ##############################################
    # Так как данная строка передается в subrocess - исполнение произвольного кода нам ни к чему. 
    # Удалим пробелы назло кул хакерам.
    prod_id_key = r_prog_id.replace(' ', '')

Comment: Ну будут использовать другие пробелы, в юникоде их сотни :)

Comment: Там cp1251  - не прокатит :)

Comment: Что cp1251 забыл в 2017 году?

Comment: Ну в данном случае это оказалось наруку безопасности. А так то да.

Comment: На руку безопасности окажется нормальная фильтрация lic_request — нужно не удалять запрещённые символы, а оставлять разрешённые

Comment: rdata = data.decode('hex').decode('cp1251') - Через этот фильтр только нормальные пробелы пройдут, а их replace убъет.

Comment: в данном случае идеален вариант типа reg = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z-]')